# React-router-dom concatenates the URLs, but there isn`t any render occured

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new with React-router-dom 6^4 lib. Have a trouble.
Using c-r-a template, already have 2 simple components (Log In Form and Sign Up Form).
According to the docs I must create an instance of BrouserRouter in the entry point.

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
  }
])

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Then add my components to router as children

```
children: [
      {
        path: "sign_up",
        element: <SignUp />
      },
      {
        path: "log_in",
        element: <LogIn />
      }   ]
```

,
and create links in App component

```
<Link to={"sign_up"}>Sign Up</Link>
<Link to={"log_in"}>Log In</Link>
```

In the end i see links, React-router-dom concatenates the URLs I passed to  'path' prop, but there isn`t any render occured. Where did I make a mistake?

All required imports are kept. Maybe I should pass to the 'path' prop relative path to my comp, but it isn`t work too.
[Git](https://github.com/MMMorpheus/Form.git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add **`<Outlet />`** (part of react-router-dom) in parent route element (your case - in `App`). This place will draw current sub-route data.

Check out this doc - https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/start/tutorial.md#nested-routes